# Syntax of priority queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, operator-overloading, priority-queue

why do we need 3 parameters for creating a priority queue with user-defined comparison .

```
priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, comp> pq;
```

why cant we write something like `priority_queue<Node*, comp> pq;`(removed vector<node*>) to create our own comparison operator.
What is the purpose of vector<node*> ?

Also how are the elements taken for comparison, and pushed into the queue after comparison.

How does overloading occur here.

Comment: Just like arguments in a function call, you can't skip "arguments" in a template.

Comment: I've never understood why `std::vector` is the default there.  A priority_queue is often faster with a `std::deque` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you see the `std::priority_queue` delectation, you can see second and third template parameter is defaulted in `std` implementation.

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

When you do `priority_queue<Node*, com>` so here `com` is second parameter, but   in the declaration it is third. so to set it to exact third position we need to add the second parameter as well, just like functions where we have to add default parameters to the right of function param list.

This is how `std::priority_queue` is designed, as `std::vector` is used as a default container, so adding it at second position gives us flexibility to use our own containers instead of `std::vector`. As it happens to be in the middle of other default parameter list, so to set the right most default parameters, the default parameters coming its way has to be set as well. It's the language requirement.

If you understand priority-queue, it uses `heap` which stores your data in such an order based on the comparator you provided, so that the (lets say) maximum element is on top, priority-queue, insert and extract the data using that comparator. Which is by default `std::less` which require you to provide overload for `<` operator for your type you are trying to put in `prirotiy_queue` in you case it is `Node`. If you want to set your own priority criteria, you can provide such an overload.

Comment: what more could we achieve using vector<node*> ?

Comment: We  do not achieve anything, this is how `priority_queue` is designed, so that we can use other containers which support the operations supported by std::vector. As std::vector is defaulted at second position to add comparator to  third position we have add second.

Answer (score 2):

> why cant we write something like priority_queue<Node*, comp> pq;(removed vector<node*>) to create our own comparison operator.

It is no problem to just define the shortcut you would like to have, by just aliasing the specific type of interest (priority queues with vector as container type):

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Cmp = std::less<typename std::vector<T>::value_type>>
using vector_priority_queue = std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Cmp>;

vector_priority_queue<int> pq;
vector_priority_queue<int, comp> pq2;
```